# Shorthand/function for adding to variable if defined or assigning to it?

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorthand or function for writing the following?

```
x  = x? x+1 : 1
```

Recently I have found myself needing to frequently check if some nested object atttribute has been defined yet, and if it has, increment it, which makes the line above very long. Something like:

```
object1[atttribute1][atttribute2][atttribute3] = object1[atttribute1][atttribute2][atttribute3]? object1[atttribute1][atttribute2][atttribute3]+1:1;
```

I am wondering if there is some built-in function that can do this? Along the lines of:

```
x = performActionIfExistsOrAssignDefault(x, add1, 1)
function add1(x){
    return x+1;
}
```

Comment: There is no shorthand, sorry. Initialize your variables!

Comment: Why don't you make it two lines and save the value of `object1[attribute1][attribute2][attribute3]` to a variable

Comment: `x  = (x || 0) + 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no magic built in for this (although you could create a function yourself), but there is a significantly shorter way to write this:

```
x = (x || 0) + 1
```

This can translate to arrays like in your second example, as well

```
object1 = (object1 || [])
object1[attr1] = (object1[attr1] || [])
```

This method can also be used to access deeply nested objects if you don't know that the properties exist:

```
var something = (((obj || {}).prop1) || {}).prop2 || {}).prop3;
```